# How to show Circular ProgressBar which have more than three colors

Tags: android, android-progressbar

[image]

[image]

I have to only show progress From 0 -100% Not Downloading. For example, with the ProgressBar shown, the first image is showing 25%, the second is 50%.

I have searched and there are lot of questions, but there are no answers related to my requirement. I have tried with Gradient but in Gradient we can set a maximum of three colours. But here I have to set four to five colours.

Comment: use a RadialGradient it can hava ant number of colors